# Convolution of two bipolar rectangular pulses

Tags: digital-communications, pulse

I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around what the convolution of two identical rectangular pulses that go from amplitude +A to -A with period T looks like. Please see my drawing below.

[image]

I know that when a pulse has amplitude 0 to A, the resulting convolution of two identical pulses is a triangular pulse from 0 to 2T. For a pulse from -A to A, would the resulting convolution be a triangular pulse shifted down?

EDIT: Here is my attempt with integrals:
[image]

EDIT 2: Here is my second attempt. I got stuck setting it up I think.
[image]

EDIT3: This time I think I figured it out a bit more, I needed to vertically shift the rectangular pulse I think. But then when I get to the integral I get pretty stuck.
[image]

Comment: You're trying to do something that confuses you purely by the power of intuition. That won't work. Write down the formula for convolution, and insert your rectangular functions, verify that you get the triange in the first case, and then try with your -A / A rectangle. Where's the problem with that integral?

Comment: That's just it, I have no problem doing the convolution for the first case with the integrals, I just can't figure out how to even set up the integral for the second case.

Comment: well, there's no "setting up". Give your function a name, e.g. $r(t)$, write down the integral with the function in it, post it here, then discuss where the problem lies :)

Comment: How do I post it in a comment? Do I need to add it to my post? @MarcusMüller

Comment: adding it to your post by editing it would be preferable :)

Comment: Added to my post, thanks! @MarcusMüller

Comment: uh, you didn't give your function a name, and putting "$(A-(-A))$" in there instead is the source of all your problems. Please, really, be strict with yourself and really write down just the formula for convolution, and then *after* insert the values of the rectangle function. You're skipping steps, although you're not sure on your feet while walking; again, you're trying to apply intuition where you're confused, and that still won't work :)

Comment: Look, I've been attempting this problem for hours now. I'm trying to do what you say, but it's clear that I'm not very knowledgeable here. I've edited my post with my latest attempt, but I'm clearly very lost and your hints are not helping me but adding to my confusion. I'm a visual person and I would appreciate just a clear explanation of maybe the set up needed to solve this problem. I would really just appreciate a breakdown of what I'm doing wrong instead of vague hints about how my math is sloppy. I _know_ it's sloppy, that's why I'm asking for help!

Comment: @mhold You're describing your functions s(t) and h(t) wrongly as (A-(-A)). Describe them as x-shifted and y-shifted boxcars correctly then plug them into the convolution integral. This is where the discussion can start.

Comment: @mhold problem is that visually trying to understand diverging integrals won't work. Most of the things I convolve can't be "visualized" mentally at all. Nobody does convolution as the first thing in university – I'm 100% certain you had less tangible math before. You might really benefit from **not** trying to find an intuitive picture for that. You being able to deal with these kinds of operations on the pure integral level is definitely one of the skills you'll need to have in the courses that build upon the "signals and systems" course that I guess you're currently doing.

Comment: @mhold that's me saying sorry, the excuse "I'm a visual person" simply doesn't work: you'll need to be able to deal with the integrals and putting in function in these, anyway. But this is also me saying "if you made it this far, you'll manage, promised"; I know the frustration when one can't build up a "mental image" of something, but sometimes one just needs to deal with that. Later, mental images of different kinds do manifest; but for a beginner, the important step is to let go of the mental image and learn the more general formulaic idea. (your mental images just break down all the time)

Comment: Okay well I gave it another go. I tried to vertically shift the rectangular pulse like was mentioned. I can't tell if I did it properly so if you could let me know if that's correct I'd appreciate it. My problem is that due to my course sequence I took signals over a year ago and no the course I'm taking relies on it and I'm having trouble remembering the basics :/ 

Now what I'm stuck on is the integral part. It looks pretty complicated so I'm not very sure I did it right. I don't understand how to do an integral for two rectangular pulses where one is shifted without doing it graphically.

Comment: That looks good! Now, I'm sure you can split your integral :)